# Laravel 5 Elixir: How to mix copy multiple files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-elixir

How do I mix copy multiple files with Elixir?

This does not work:

```
mix.copy([
    ['node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js', 'resources/assets/js/vendor/vue.js'],
    ['node_modules/vue-resource/dist/vue-resource.js', 'resources/assets/js/vendor/vue-resource.js']
]);
```

Any other suggestions except:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js', 'resources/assets/js/vendor/vue.js');
mix.copy('node_modules/vue-resource/dist/vue-resource.js', 'resources/assets/js/vendor/vue-resource.js');
```

Comment: Add them to an array, and pass that to the functions.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `mix.copy()` expect two strings so passing an array will not work. I fixed it by creating an object called directories like this:

```
var directories = {
  'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js': 'resources/assets/js/vendor/vue.js',
  'node_modules/vue-resource/dist/vue-resource.js': 'resources/assets/js/vendor/vue-resource.js'
}
```

Then we can loop on that object like this:

```
for (directory in directories) {
  mix.copy(directory, directories[directory]);
}
```

This should work.